# Submenu Positioning

Tags: html, css, submenu

(I HAVE SINCE UPDATED THE CODE TO REFLECT THE WORKING CODE. THE CODE BELOW WORKS NOW)

Ive been working on trying to position a submenu. For the record, I have done my homework over the last week trying to make this work but I think I am messing up somewhere with my parent/child relationships.

What I am trying to do is place a menu in a column on a page, then, when hovering, have a submenu appear to its right hand side. THE PROBLEM is that my menu appears but when I resize the page, it the submenu jumps all over the place. It looks like my relative and absolute positions are the problems but I cant see where

Here is my CSS code:

```
#col1
{
background-color:#000033;
width:15%;
height:100%;
float:left;
color:#FFF000;
font-family: bold;
font-size: 100%;
}


ul.nav li 
{
position:relative;
float:left;
width:100%;
}

ul.nav a
{
display: block;
background-color:#B2B2D9;
margin-right:3%;
margin-bottom:1%;
margin-left:1%;
text-decoration:none;
border-top-color:#FFFFFF;
border-right-color:#E6E6E6;
border-bottom-color:#FFFFFF;
border-left-color:#E6E6E6;
border-top-width: 3%;
border-right-width: 3%;
border-bottom-width: 3%;
border-left-width: 3%;
border-top-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
padding: 2%;
}


ul.nav
{
position:relative;
list-style-type: none;
padding-left:0px;
line-height:1.5em;
}

ul.nav2 a
{
display: block;
background-color:#000033;
border:solid 3px black;
padding:5%; 
margin-right:0px;
margin-bottom:0%;
margin-left:0%;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
border-top-color:#FFFFFF;    
border-right-color:#E6E6E6;
border-bottom-color:#FFFFFF;
border-left-color:#E6E6E6;
}


ul.nav2
{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:100%;
display:none;
font-size:100%;
list-style-type: none;
width:8em;
line-height:1.5em;
float: none;
clear: none;
margin: 0px;
}

ul.nav2 li 
{
display:block;
margin-left:-2.8em;
width:100%;
line-height:1.3em;
}
```

Here is my HTML and JavaScript:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav').hover(function (e) {
        $('.nav2').slideDown('normal');
    }, function () {
        $('.nav2').slideUp('normal');
    });
});

</script>
</head>

 <body>

<div id="banner">
<img src="images/banner.jpg" width="100%" alt="banner" />
</div>

<div id="wrapper">


<div id="col1">

<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="http://www.ahome.com">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.ab.com">About</a></li>

    <ul class="nav2">
  <li><a href="http://www.albio.com">Bio</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.acred.com">Credentials</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.aled.com">Education</a></li>
  </ul>

<li><a href="http://www.anew.com">New Listings</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.afeat.com">Featured Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.atow.com">Town Facts</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.acme.com">Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>


</div>


<div id="main">
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, my menu is the problem. Can someone get me pointed in the right direction?

Comment: You have posted *a lot* of (not all too friendly formatted) code, surely it can't be all relevant? If you trim it and make it as [short as possible](http://sscce.org/) it's much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Ok I did.... sorry bout that!

Comment: Heres a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u74q2/. added `position: relative` to your `ul.nav1` because `nav2` was inside of it. and added `left:100%` to make it stay always to the right

Comment: Why don't you start with a working dropdown menu example like: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu and add your styling 1 line at a time, while trying not to break it.  Sometimes its just faster to start over.

Comment: It's invalid HTML to nest a `ul` tag directly within another `ul` tag. This may or may not be part of the problem (in some browsers). The inner `ul` tag should be inside one of the outer `li` tags (or a descendant of one of the `li` tags).

Comment: Thank you to all who helped. I updated the code above as it is now working. I adjusted the nav2 ul to have a negative margin on the left side.

Comment: Is your intention to have this submenu appear when the mouse is over the "About" menu (and not when it's over any of the other menu choices)? If so, it should be nested within the `li` tag for the "About" menu, and the jQuery code should be updated to act on that `li` tag rather than on '.nav'.

Comment: You are right Matt, I caught that after the fact. That part was just an error on my end due to carelessness. The real issue here laid in two parts. One was that when I set padding to 0 on my ULs, the lists shifted into place. Apparently I had some invisible default padding on my ULs to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need this way. If you are able to change the HTML and tweak the CSS a little, you can achieve this.

#### HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
* {font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma;}
ul.nav {border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
ul.nav li a {display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #333; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav > li:hover {border: 1px solid #666; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav li a:hover {background: #ccc; border: 1px solid #999;}
ul.nav > li {display: inline-block; position: relative; border: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav > li ul {display: none; position: absolute; left: -1px; width: 150px; border: 1px solid #666; border-top-color: #fff; margin-top: 1px;}
ul.nav > li:hover ul {display: block;}
ul.nav > li ul li {display: block;} /* Vertical Menu */
ul.nav > li ul li {display: inline-block;} /* Horizontal Menu */
```

#### Fiddle:
 http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/ (Vertical Menu)
 http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/1/ (Horizontal Menu)

Comment: I resolved it above but I will save your example for future use!